# cakePHP- saveAssociated() update

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have two models, donors hasMany donations.

Upon  creation of donor record, I want to  update some donor fields. I tried using saveAssociated() as follows

```
$this->Donation->create();
$this->request->data['Donation']['donor_id'] = $id;
$this->request->data['Donor']['last_donated'] = date('Ymd H:i:s', strtotime('now'));            

if($this->Donation->saveAssociated($this->request->data , array('deep' => true))){
}
```

Everything works except that the donor is not updated but a new donor record is created altogether.
Do I need to set the donor id manually somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"Do I need to set the donor id manually somehow ?"*

Yes.

**More explanation**:

In cake, if you want to update something, you need to pass the id, otherwise you'll create a new record. You can also "load" the model instance like

```
$this->Model->id = $id;
```

and then the save will update the row with that id. But I always find it more mentally-safe to add the id to the saved array, specially when using `saveAll`, `saveMany` and `saveAssociated`.

In your case, you must have the donor's id somewhere, cake is not that magical and it won't know what donor you are refering to.

Something like this

```
$this->request->data['Donor']['id'] = $the_id;
```

will do the trick.

... or you can save the donor's last_donated time with a different query, if it's giving you too much trouble.

Comment: Hi Nunser.. thanks for your thorough explanation! This worked as expected. Thanks again!